# Exclude Path in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

What is the correct JSON to exclude certain keys from an input json to be not indexed by Azure CosmosDB. We are using the CosmosDB in mongodb mode. Was planning to change the index configuration on the Azure Portal after creating the collection.

Sample Input Json being

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "age": 1,
    "location": "l1",
    "height":5.7
}
```

If I were to include name and age in the index and remove location and height from the index, what does the includedPaths and excludedPaths look like.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation on the Azure portal around customizing the index policy?

Comment: @DavidMakogon : I did, however it was not very clear. In the mongoDB mode, there are additional keys that the API adds which need to be under the index specs. Some of them being _ts, _attachments etc. Just covered them all by a * in the include spec and stated the ones I don't require in the exclude specs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got it to work with the below spec:-

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [{
        "path": "/*",
        "indexes": [{
                "kind": "Range",
                "dataType": "Number",
                "precision": -1
            },
            {
                "kind": "Hash",
                "dataType": "String",
                "precision": 3
            }
        ]
    }],
    "excludedPaths": [{
            "path": "/\"location\"/?"
        },
        {
            "path": "/\"height\"/?"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: At the time of writing, the Azure Portal gives the following error message for invalid paths: The indexing path '...' could not be accepted, failed near position '0'. Please ensure that the path is a valid path. Common errors include invalid characters or absence of quotes around labels. For better readabilty, single quotes work just as well: "path":"'height'/?"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like underlying implementation has changed and at the time of writing the documentation does not cover changing indexPolicy in MongoDB flavoured CosmosBD. Because the documents are really stored in a wired way where all the keys start from root $v and all scalar fields are stored as documents, containing value and type information. So your document will be stored something like:

```
{
  '_etag': '"2f00T0da-0000-0d00-0000-4cd987940000"',
  'id': 'SDSDFASDFASFAFASDFASDF',
  '_self': 'dbs/sMsxAA==/colls/dVsxAI8MBXI=/docs/sMsxAI8MBXIKAAAAAAAAAA==/',
  '_rid': 'sMsxAI8MBXIKAAAAAAAAAA==',
  '$t': 3,
  '_attachments': 'attachments/',
  '$v': {
    '_id': {
      '$t': 7,
      '$v': "\\Ù\x87\x14\x01\x15['\x18m\x01ú"
    },
    'name': {
      '$t': 2,
      '$v': 'test'
    },
    'age': {
      '$t': 1,
      '$v': 1
    },
    ...
  },
  '_ts': 1557759892
}
```

Therefore the indexingPolicy paths need to include the root $v and use /* (objects) instead of /? (scalars).

```
{
  "indexingMode": "consistent",
  "automatic": true,
  "includedPaths": [
    {
      "path": "/*",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "Number"
        },
        {
          "kind": "Hash",
          "dataType": "String"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "excludedPaths": [
    {"path": "/\"$v\"/\"location\"/*"},
    {"path": "/\"$v\"/\"height\"/*"}
  ]
}
```

PS: 
Also mongo api can be used to drop all the default indexes and create specific indexes as required 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing